# laravel hyn/multi-tenancy override login method using tenant db redirect again login page try to redirect homepage

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

In hyn/multi-tenancy after overriding the login method in LoginController and within this method connect the tenant database. It login successfully if I print the login results but when I redirect it to homeController it again redirects to the Login Page and doesn't go to the home page. I use
https://github.com/peartreedigital/boilerplate
example only change in loginController which is

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

public function username()
{   
    $login = request()->input('identity');
    $field = filter_var($login, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
    request()->merge([$field => $login]);
    return $field;
}

protected $redirectTo = '/home';

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $messages = [
        'identity.required' => 'Email or username cannot be empty',
        'email.exists' => 'Email or username already registered',
        'username.exists' => 'Username is already registered',
        'password.required' => 'Password cannot be empty',
    ];

    $request->validate([
        'identity' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'string|exists:users',
        'username' => 'string|exists:users',
    ], $messages);

    $domain_name = $request->get('domain_name');
    $usernameatacc = $request->get('identity');
    $password = $request->get('password');

    $hostname = DB::table('hostnames')->select('*')->where('fqdn', $domain_name)->first();
    $dbname = DB::table('websites')->select('uuid')->where('id', $hostname->website_id)->first();

    Config::set("database.connections.tenant", [
        "driver"   => 'mysql',
        "host" => '127.0.0.1',
        "database" => $dbname->uuid,
        "username" => 'root',
        "password" => ''
    ]);

    Config::set('database.default', 'tenant');
    DB::purge('tenant');
    DB::reconnect('tenant');
}

 public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);
    $user_data = User::where('email', $request->get('identity'))
        ->first();
    $matchPwd = Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user_data->password);
    if ($matchPwd == '1') {
        // print_r($user_data);
        // Here What can I do????? Please help
    }else {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($user_data);
    }

} 


protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}

}
```

My login form in login.blade.php is

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="domain_name" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Domain Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="domain_name" type="domain_name" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="domain_name" value="{{ old('domain_name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('domain_name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('domain_name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="identity" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect user after login with defining either method of `redirectTo()` or property of `$redirectTo`.

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    if (User::check()) {
        return route('home');
    }
}
```

or

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

Be careful about referring to the name that you've assigned in the route file (default: web.php).

Comment: I am new to laravel also new to hyn. please help
There already has protected $redirectTo = '/home';
If I want to use redirectTo() method then please give what things need to do within check() method in User model.

This is my web.php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'tenancy.enforce'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');